# varbinary(max) - table size

Tags: sql-server, database-size

I have an application database (not of my design) with a table for storing files in a varbinary(max) column. These databases show to take up 2X the actually required space (i.e. shrink shows give/take 50% free, but will not shrink).

If I run dbcc cleantable followed by a reindex of the clustered index and shrink the file then the size makes more sense.

The problem is that when the older index maintenance rebuilds the index, the file reverts to having an abundance of free space.

I have modified the index maintenance to exclude this clustered index - so it currently isn't an issue.

What I can't figure out is the technical explanation as to why this happens - if someone could shed some light on this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps the other index maintenance solution was setting a lowered fill factor?

Comment: Nope, checked that too - it had no fill or pad. The clustered index is on an identity column and the data is normally only 1-way (into the table). The clustered index shouldn't fragment normally, so I believe it is ok to skip it on daily maintenance. I just can't determine why the cleantable and index allows reclamation of the space, but an index rebuild balloons it back. Something that the cleantable > reindex does that a reindex by itself does not deal with? It's just bugging me :)

I wouldn't generally worry, but one of the databases has close to a TB of 'slack' space.

Comment: Is it the data file (MDF) or log file (LDF) that you're seeing the *abundance of free space* in?

Comment: An online index rebuild builds the new index, then "swaps" it for the old one at the very end. Hence, if you are rebuilding all your indexes, your database needs free space for your largest index to be rebuilt. Is your free space just a little bigger than your largest index?

Comment: JD - it is the data file. AMtwo - the rebuild is offline but yes - the database only has that one table and the free space sits at 50% after the rebuild

Comment: OK what is different about the index rebuild command you are doing versus the other one?

Comment: well - I found this https://sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-space-required-rebuild-index-operation/   The table only has one table - so rebuilding the clustered index would result in two copies - thus 2X the size - if I'm reading that right. I guess I just never notice that when the index doesn't include a varbinary with large files.